# Highligting widgets in QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm using a QListWidget as a selector of channels for an (somewhat modified) IRC client. I would like to indicate several things, such as unread messages, using QSS to style the entries. So far I have code like this:

```cpp
class MainWindow : public QWidget {
    QListWidgtet *channels;
    
    MainWindow() {
        channels = new QListWidget(this);
        addChannel("test");
        addChannel("test2");
        QObject::connect(channels, &QListWidget::currentItemChanged, this, &MainWindow::changeChannel);
        setStyleSheet("QLabel[selected=\"true\"] { color: #ff0000; }");
    }
    
    void addChannel(QString name) {
        QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(name, channels);
        QLabel* l = new QLabel(name);
        l->setProperty("selected", false);
        channels->addItem(item);
        channels->setItemWidget(item, l);
    }

    void changeChannel(QListWidgetItem *current, QListWidgetItem *previous) {
        //do stuff
        channels->itemWidget(current)->setProperty("selected", true);
        if (previous != nullptr) 
            channels->itemWidget(previous)->setProperty("selected", false);
    }
};
```

I understand I can use the `QListWidget::item:selected` in the QSS, however I want to have other properties, such as unread, with unique QSS styling too. The problem with this code is that it doesn't update dynamically. If I set the default (aka value set in the `addChannel` function) to true, then it displays the correct styling, however if I set the default to false and then set it to true when clicked, it does not display the correct styling. How can I fix this, or am I going about it completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call polish() of the QStyle for the painting to be updated.

```
if(QWidget *current_widget = channels->itemWidget(current)){
    current_widget->setProperty("selected", true);
    current_widget->style()->polish(current_widget);
}
if (QWidget *previous_widget = channels->itemWidget(previous)){
    previous_widget->setProperty("selected", false);
    previous_widget->style()->polish(previous_widget);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way .

```
l->setStyleSheet("QLabel[selected=\"true\"] { color: #ff0000; }");
```